# Finding Lyapunov function to control the Duffing Oscillator

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

I'm trying to do this exercise but I'm struggling to find the Lyapunov function.
We have the state version of the Duffing oscillator below:

$\dot{x_1} = x_2$ 
$\dot{x_2} = x_1 - x_1^3 - \delta x_2$

which results in the unforced Duffing oscillator if δ = 0, and the damped Duffing oscillator for δ > 0.

We want:

1. Identify the fixed points and their local stability properties.
2. Find a Lyapunov or Lyapunov-like function for the stable fixed point(s).
3. Use the function to characterize the size of the region of attraction for the damped version at each fixed point.

What i did is:

1. I find the fixed points : (0,0);(1,0);(-1,0) and I compute the jacobian for each fixed points to look at their local stability. 
   I find that the points (1,0);(-1,0) have the same jacobian and are stable when $\delta \gt 0$ and the point (0,0) is not stable.
2. I tried with the lyapunov function: 
   $V(x_1,x_2)=\frac 12 (x_1^2+x_2^2)$ 
   And I got: 
   $\dot V(x_1,x_2) =2x_1x_2-x_2x_1^3-\delta x_2^2$ 
   Which is not $\lt 0$ 
   So I was thinking trying something like: 
   $V(x_1,x_2)=\alpha x_1^m+\beta x_2^n$ 
   But after computing the derivative it seems to give nothing too. 
   Do you have any suggestion for the lyapunov function?
3. For this part honestly I don't really know what to do maybe I was thinking of finding a lyapunov function at the question 2 which is negative for a region on $x_1$ or $x_2$.

Comment: Your Lyapunov function has its minimum at the *unstable* fixed point $(0,0)$, so it's useless for investigating $(\pm 1,0)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Jacobian that you obtained for the stable equilibrium points $(-1, 0)$, and $(1, 0)$, the linearized system becomes

$$ \left[\matrix{\dot{x}_{1} \cr \dot{x}_{2}}\right] = \left[\matrix{0 & 1 \cr -2 & -\delta}\right] \left[\matrix{x_{1} \cr x_{2}}\right] .$$

Consider the Lyapunov function in the following quadratic form:

$$ V(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{x}^{T} \mathbf{P} \mathbf{x} = \frac{1}{2} \left[\matrix{x_{1} & x_{2}}\right] \left[\matrix{\frac{\delta^{2} + 2 \delta + 2}{\delta} & 1 \cr 1 & \frac{\delta + 1}{\delta}}\right] \left[\matrix{x_{1} \cr x_{2}}\right] .$$

The positive definite $\mathbf{P}$ is found by solving the Lyapunov equation $\mathbf{P} \mathbf{A} + \mathbf{A}^{T} \mathbf{P} = - \mathbf{Q}$. In this case, $\mathbf{Q}$ is chosen as

$$ \mathbf{Q} = \left[\matrix{2 & 0 \cr 0 & \delta}\right] .$$

The derivative of $V(\mathbf{x})$ along the trajectories of the linear system is given by

$$ \dot{V}(\mathbf{x}) = - 2 x_{1}^{2} - \delta x_{2}^{2} < 0 \quad \text{for} \quad \mathbf{x} \neq \mathbf{0} .$$

Remember that this result, however, is local.

**Region of Attraction**

To estimate the region of attraction, the previous Lyapunov function can be used to determine a domain $D$ about the stable equilibrium by solving the derivative of $V(\mathbf{x})$ along the trajectories of the nonlinear system (Duffing Oscillator) where $\dot{V}(\mathbf{x})$ is negative definite.

$$ \dot{V} = \left(\frac{\delta^{2} + 2 \delta + 2}{\delta}\right) x_{1} \dot{x}_{1} + \dot{x}_{1} x_{2} + x_{1} \dot{x}_{2} + \left(\frac{\delta + 1}{\delta}\right) x_{2} \dot{x}_{2} $$

$$ \dot{V} = \left(\frac{\delta^{2} + 2 \delta + 2}{\delta}\right) x_{1} x_{2} + x_{2}^{2} + x_{1} \left(x_{1} - x_{1}^{3} - \delta x_{2}\right) + \left(\frac{\delta + 1}{\delta}\right) x_{2} \left(x_{1} - x_{1}^{3} - \delta x_{2}\right) $$

$$ \dot{V} = - x_{1}^{4} - \left[\left(\frac{\delta + 1}{\delta}\right) x_{1} x_{2} - 1\right] x_{1}^{2} + \left(\frac{3 \delta + 3}{\delta}\right) x_{1} x_{2} - \delta x_{2}^{2} $$

For example, if $\delta = 1$, the region of attraction is found to be satisfied in $D_{(1, 0)} = \left\{\sqrt{2} < x_{1} < \sqrt{5}, x_{2} \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$, and $D_{(-1, 0)} = \left\{-\sqrt{5} < x_{1} < -\sqrt{2}, x_{2} \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$.

The streamplot for the Duffing Oscillator with $\delta = 1$ is shown below. Note that $\pm \sqrt{5} \approx \pm 2.236$.

[image]

Comment: Does this P come from $A^TP+AP=-Q$ ? If it is the case do you choose randomly your Q? Why don't just take Q=identity ?

Comment: I tried with Q=identity it works too we just find another P but we have the same result. \
Now I have that how can I have a region of attraction since the lyapunov function is good for every x, it should be R ? But if the region of attraction is R then we can say it is global?

Comment: @Luki26, Yes, the positive definite matrix $\mathbf{P}$ is obtained by solving the Lyapunov equation. You can choose $\mathbf{Q}$ as you wish so long as it is a positive definite matrix. The estimation for Region of Attraction is added in the edited Answer.

Comment: After $\delta = 1$ how do you find your region of interest? Do you find it by solving the inequality $\dot{V} = - x_{1}^{4} - (2x_1x_2-1)x_1^2+6x_1x_2-x_2^2 \lt 0$? Because I'm trying like this but I do not succeed to find the same answer. I think I miss something because I don't use both equilibrium in my computation.

Comment: @Luki26, I used WolframAlpha to solve the inequality. [Click here to see result on WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=find+-+x%5E4+-+%282*x*y+-+1%29*x%5E2+%2B+6*x*y+-+y%5E2+%3C+0)